# UBSDKRideRequesting authenticating issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uber-api

I tried to login with that code which is give below - with or without using redirect_URI but it always show error 
1.There was a problem in authenticating you.Please try again later

I checked my whole project but there is no any other issue I found.

```
id<UBSDKRideRequesting> behavior = [[UBSDKRideRequestViewRequestingBehavior alloc] initWithPresentingViewController: self];
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 37.787654 longitude: -122.402760];
UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
[builder setPickupLocation:location];

 UBSDKRideParameters *parameters = [builder build];
 UBSDKRideRequestButton *button = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] initWithRideParameters: parameters requestingBehavior: behavior];
 button.frame=CGRectMake(10,self.view.frame.size.height+self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width-20,50) ;
  [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Please help me to solve my issue.
Thanks

Comment: Can you also share your Info.plist (with your sensitive keys removed)? Your mention of "with or without using redirect_URI" leads me to believe this is an sdk setup issue.

Comment: file:///Users/codefyne/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-01%20at%2011.56.00%20AM.png i have mentioned redirect URL also

Comment: I know you mentioned redirect URL but I would like to see if you have it set correctly in your .plist. Can you edit your question to include the screenshot you attempted to post here?